# Lista de bitarray en python

Tags: python

Buenas a todos chicos,

Estoy "jugando" un poco con los bitarrays en python y me ha surgido un problema y no se como solucionarlo, os comento:

Tengo un bitarray llamado aux compuesto por 6 ceros y un 1 tal que '0000001'.
La idea es guardar en una lista las combinaciones que existen moviendo el 1 en todo el bitarray, es decir, una lista que sea: {['0000001'],['0000010'],['0000100'],['0001000'],['0010000'],['0100000'],['1000000']}.

El caso es que las modificaciones sobre aux para mover el 1 a la izquierda todo el rato funciona correctamente pero a la hora de añadirlo a la lista, me modifica todos los valores de la lista en lugar de guardarlos separados. Os dejo mi código y las capturas de pantalla para que lo veáis. PD (Se que el algoritmo no funciona para cualquier bitarray pero solo necesito que funcione para el ejemplo que os comento)

Código del Programa:

```
Lista = []

aux = bitarray('00000001') #Creo el bitarray

Lista.append(aux) #Lo añado a la lista como primer elemento

#Muestro el elemento y la lista para ver que se ha añadido
#todo correctamente
print("La lista es: " , Lista)
print("Aux: " , aux)

while(aux[0] == False): #Bucle que se repite hasta que la primera 
    #Posicion del bitarray sea un 1
    aux.remove(False) #Eliminamos la primera posicion
    aux.append(False) #Insertamos un 0 al final para mover todo a la izquierda
    print("*Aux despues del append: " , aux) #Mostramos aux despues de los cambios
    Lista.append(aux) #Añadimos aux MODIFICADO a la lista
    print("**La lista es: " , Lista) # Mostramos la lista

print("Aux despues de toda esta movida: " , aux) #Vemos como ha quedado aux

print("------------------------------------------------------------")

#Mostramos la lista posicion a posicion de forma detallada y visual
for i in range (len(Lista)):
    print("Posicion ",i,": ",Lista[i])
```

Y esta es la salida por pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos y feliz año nuevo!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás usando siempre la misma variable `aux` que modificas y metes en la lista.

Ya que en Python todas las variables son en realidad referencias a objetos, cuando haces `Lista.append(aux)` lo que metes en esa lista es una referencia a la variable `aux`. Si después cambias el valor de esa variable, aunque la referencia sigue apuntando al mismo lugar, el contenido habrá variado.

Para que lo veas más simple:

```
lista = []
aux = bitarray('00000001')
lista.append(aux)
aux.append(True)
print(aux)
print(lista)
```

```
bitarray('000000011')
[bitarray('000000011')]
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un nuevo bitarray que sea una copia de `aux`. Las referencias serán entonces diferentes, y así no se modificará la variable original que ya estaba en la lista:

```
lista = []
aux = bitarray('00000001')
lista.append(aux)
aux = aux.copy()
aux.append(True)
print(aux)
print(lista)
```

```
bitarray('000000011')
[bitarray('00000001')]
```

En tu caso, bastaría sacar esta copia al principio del bucle:

```
while(aux[0] == False): #Bucle que se repite hasta que la primera 
    aux = aux.copy()   # <----- AÑADIR ESTO
    #Posicion del bitarray sea un 1
    aux.remove(False) #Eliminamos la primera posicion
    aux.append(False) #Insertamos un 0 al final para mover todo a la izquierda
    print("*Aux despues del append: " , aux) #Mostramos aux despues de los cambios
    Lista.append(aux) #Añadimos aux MODIFICADO a la lista
    print("**La lista es: " , Lista) # Mostramos la lista
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya funciona. No sabia que python se comportaba de esa forma con las variables por eso me fallaba. Lo dicho muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Si sabes algo de C, te puede servir como modelo mental para entender muchas cosas de python el imaginar que en realidad _todas las variables son punteros_. En python `a=3` crea un objeto de tipo entero en memoria, almacena allí un 3, y hace que `a` "apunte" a ese dato. Cuando más tarde haces `a=a+1`, por ejemplo, se crea otro objeto con el valor 4 y se cambia la referencia de `a` para que apunte a ese 4, abandonándose el 3 que queda sin referencias y puede ser recolectado por el recolector de basura. Una lista contiene referencias (punteros) a sus elementos, etc.

Comment: Al hacer `aux=bitarray("...")` se crea un objeto y `aux` "apunta" a él. Al hacer `aux.metodo()` ese metodo operará sobre el dato apuntado. Si haces `aux=aux.copy()` se crea un nuevo objeto, se copian los datos del primero, y se cambia el "puntero" `aux` para que apunte al segundo, perdiéndose la referencia al primero (pero de todas formas en tu caso esa referencia sigue dentro de la `Lista`, por lo que el recolector de basura no lo quitará de memoria)

Comment: Sii si de C si que tengo idea y entiendo bien como funcionan los pasos por valor y por referencia lo que pasaba es que no sabia que python trabajaba asi con las variables, por eso me ha pasado esto pero bueno nunca es tarde para aprender cosas nuevas jajajaja. Muchas gracias de nuevo :)